# Formal proof: $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective if $f$ is surjective and $|A| = |B| <\infty$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Formal proof: $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective if $f$ is surjective and $|A| = |B| < \infty$

How does one proof formally that $f$ must be injective if the above criterion is satisfied ?

Informally it is easy to see $f$ must be injective, since otherwise $\exists a,a^{'} \in A: f(a)=f(a^{'})$, but then there remains $|A| - 2$ elements in $A$, $|B| - 1$ elements in $B$ and $|A| - 2 < |B| - 1$ by the assumption $|A| = |B|$, which in turn implies $f(A - \{a, a^{'}\}) \subsetneq B - \{f(a)\}$ since $|f(A - \{a, a^{'}\})| < |B - \{f(a)\}|$.

I guess you will agree this is not a very "beautiful" proof and it is probably not very rigorous ?

I will be happy to read about your thoughts and ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Are you assuming that the sets are finite?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't state that. I will do that now.

Comment: Assuming that the sets are finite, argue by induction on $|A|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because the claim is wrong.
The map $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, $n\mapsto\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor$ is surjective, but not injective.

---

However, if you consider only *finite* sets, the claim is true: Assume otherwise and let $n\in\mathbb N_0$ be minimal such that there exists a surjective non-injective function $f\colon A\to B$ with $|A|=|B|=n$. For such $f$ pick $a,b\in A$ with $a\ne b$, $f(a)=f(b)$ as $f$ is not injective. So necessarily $n\ge 2$ and we can pick $c\in B$ with $c\ne f(a)$. Define $g\colon A\setminus\{b\}\to B\setminus\{c\}$ by
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(a)&\text{if }f(x)=c\\
f(x)&\text{if }f(x)\ne c\end{cases} $$
Then $g$ is surjective and between sets with $|A\setminus\{b\}|=|B\setminus\{c\}|=n-1<n$. By surjectivity of $f$ there exists $d\in A$ with $f(d)=c$. As clearly $d\ne b$ and $d\ne a$, we find from $g(d)=g(a)$ that $g$ is not injective, contradicting minimality of $n$.

Comment: Sorry the sets are finite, forgot to state that.

Comment: Thanks I like your proof, however I find a direct proof using induction more appealing.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen You are welcome. Considering minimal counterexamples as I did (or *descens infinii*) is readily converted to a direct induction proof.